# SQL max multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, max, multiple-columns

I am trying to display the maximum value of a specific value, and the corresponding timestamp for the value.  I have the command working properly, but unfortunately, if the value is at the maximum value for more than one time period, it displays all of the timestamps.  This can be cumbersome with multiple targets as well.  Here is what I am using now:

```
select target_name,value,collection_timestamp 
from (select target_name,value,collection_timestamp,
             max(value) over (partition by target_name) max_value
      from mgmt$metric_details 
      where target_type='host' and metric_name='TotalDiskUsage' 
        and column_label='Total Disk Utilized (%) (across all local filesystems)'
     )
where value=max_value;
```

I want to utilize the same kind of command (trying to avoid inner joins etc, because of the lack of bandwidth)....but only show 1 max value/timestamp per target_name.  Is there a way to coordinate a group by or limit function into this, without breaking it?  I am somewhat unfamiliar with SQL, so this is all new territory.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified.  Oracle Database 11g

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query is so close.  Instead of doing the `max`, do a `row_number()`:

```
select target_name,value,collection_timestamp 
from (select target_name,value,collection_timestamp,
             row_number() over (partition by target_name order by value desc) as seqnum
      from mgmt$metric_details 
      where target_type='host' and metric_name='TotalDiskUsage' 
        and column_label='Total Disk Utilized (%) (across all local filesystems)'
     )
where seqnum = 1
```

This orders everything in the partition by value.  You want the one largest value, so order by descending value and take the first in the sequence.

Comment: Ok, this may be my lack of experience in SQL, but I am a bit confused.  The above code is giving me a "missing window specification for this function."  Essentially what I want as a result is to show the max value of a column for each target_name and the timestamp from when that value was taken.  But if the value was at the max (say 25 for example) on 4 different days, it shows all 4 days it was at that value.  I want it to show me the max value for that target, and only show me more recent day that it was at that value...

Comment: @user1943674 @Gordon: minor typo in `row_number())`, a parenthesis needs to be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` function instead of `MAX()` and appropriate `ORDER BY` in the window to resolve the ties:

```
select target_name,value,collection_timestamp 
from (select target_name,value,collection_timestamp,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by target_name
                                ORDER BY value DESC, 
                                         collection_timestamp DESC )
                 AS rn
      from mgmt$metric_details 
      where target_type='host' and metric_name='TotalDiskUsage' 
        and column_label='Total Disk Utilized (%) (across all local filesystems)'
     )
where rn = 1 ;
```

Comment: Gordon gave the (almost exactly) same answer before me.

Comment: @bluefeet: The other answer has order too, I only make it specific (when there are ties in the maximum value)